# How to make correct use of Connection Pooling in MySQL Connector/NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mysql-connector

This has been really frustrating, so please help. [The documentation on MySQL website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connections-pooling.html) clearly states that the best practice is to not open connections manually, and to not even create command objects.

Well, I'm doing exactly that on my code - never creating a MySqlConnection object myself, and whenever I have to run queries, I use a static method from the MySqlHelper class, passing on the connection string. Here is an example

```
   public async Task<Object> GetEvalHandResultFromCloudAsync(String hand)
    {
        string query = $"SELECT strength FROM eval_hand WHERE hand = '{hand}' and status = 'completed'";
        return await MySqlHelper.ExecuteScalarAsync(SimsConnectionString, query);

    }
```

The problem I've run into is that everytime I run a query, a new connection is open from scratch. I can see that because I can monitor active connections through AWS console. This is driving me nuts because it seems clear that this is the recommended approach, however I'm not getting the expected behaviour. Every query takes a lifetime because a connection is getting opened before the query is sent to the server.

When instead of passing on the connection string to the MySqlHelper static methods I pass a previously opened MySqlConnection object, the queries run much faster and my application becomes way more responsive.

I apologize in advance because I must be doing something super simple clearly wrong but I can't see it. All of my queries use the same connection string. My understanding is that, after the first query, in which a connection must be opened, the following queries will use the previously opened connection, which is taken from the pool, without the necessity for establishing new ones. What is going here?

One thing that intrigues me is that, in the link above, the documentation states that the static methods that take connectionString as argument fully support connection pooling. But [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlHelper_ExecuteNonQuery_1.htm) the in the MySqlHelper class, the documentation says that the methods that take a connectionString open a new MySqlConnection. I thought at first this simply meant that it would take from the pool if one exists anyway, but if that was the case I feel this would have been written differently. So maybe the problem really is the method and the initial link I posted is innacurate.

Comment: I don't even see ExecuteScalarAsync in the MySqlHelper